# Adding values to UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I need to add items to a `UIDatePicker`, but instead of adding dates:

[image: shot of UIDatePicker]

I need to add a list of names (e.g., "James"). How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

```
 UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
 myPickerView.delegate = self
 myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
 [self.view addSubview:myPickerView]; 

  - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
  {
     return 1;
  }  
  - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {   
      return 1;
 }

  - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
  {
     NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:@"Jack"];
     return string;
   }
```

EDIT:1

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      //Returns the index of the selected row in a given component.
      NSLog(@"%d",component);
}
```

Comment: Can i use `- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component` method to get the row selected ? If so what will the method body look like. I simply would require to `NSLog` the selected value. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Check the following,

```
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 250)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.opaque = NO;
    [customPickerView addSubview:pickerView];

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return 10;
}
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
ILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
tView.text =  [arrList objectAtIndex:row];
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      //When ever picker view cell is pressed.
      //Write ur logic
}
```